# Biztalk 2013 <string xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'> was not expected

Tags: wcf, serialization, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a BizTalk 2013 orchestration which I published as a WCF service. The orchestration has  a Request-Response port accepting a string and returning an entity which I have defined in a schema.

When I try use the service and pass a string to it, I get the error 
**http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'> was not expected.**

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks

Full error details below:

> xlang/s engine event log entry: Uncaught exception (see the 'inner
>   exception' below) has suspended an instance of service
>   'CAA.POC.ESB.BizTalk.Orchestrations.RetrieveAllCases(c408d4a7-3795-f6c7-dc95-c02edfe00740)'.
>   The service instance will remain suspended until administratively
>   resumed or terminated.  If resumed the instance will continue from its
>   last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
>   InstanceId: 6b9cbf6a-2a63-4401-b3a1-05a870da963c Shape name:
>   ConstructCases ShapeId: 189c5a7f-2306-49dc-bd07-8430e638ba45 Exception
>   thrown from: segment 1, progress 7 Inner exception: There is an error
>   in XML document (1, 2).
>            Exception type: InvalidOperationException Source: System.Xml Target Site: System.Object Deserialize(System.Xml.XmlReader,
>   System.String, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlDeserializationEvents) The
>   following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the
>   exception occured
>
> at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
>   xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader
>   textReader)    at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Value.GetObject(Type t)    at
>   Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Value.RetrieveAs(Type t)    at
>   Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Part.ProtectedRetrieveAs(Type t)    at
>   Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Part.RetrieveAs(Type t)    at
>   CAA.POC.ESB.BizTalk.Orchestrations.**System_String**.get_TypedValue() 
>   at
>   CAA.POC.ESB.BizTalk.Orchestrations.RetrieveAllCases.segment1(StopConditions
>   stopOn)    at
>   Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.SegmentScheduler.RunASegment(Segment s,
>   StopConditions stopCond, Exception& exp) Additional error information:
>
> ```
>     <string xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'> was not
> ```
>
> expected.
>            Exception type: InvalidOperationException Source: System.Xml Target Site: System.Object Read_string() The following is a stack
>   trace that identifies the location where the exception occured
>
> at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationPrimitiveReader.Read_string()
>   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.DeserializePrimitive(XmlReader
>   xmlReader, XmlDeserializationEvents events)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
>   xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)

Comment: can you show your service code and client method?